# Все наши знакомые кроме пожалуй одного переболели этой зимой гриппом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, уточнения

*Все наши знакомые кроме пожалуй одного переболели этой зимой гриппом.*

Какие нужны знаки препинания?

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

***Все наши знакомые (кроме, пожалуй, одного) переболели этой зимой гриппом.***

Comment: Разве можно обосновать здесь отсутствие запятой после "пожалуй"?

Comment: _grizzly: Разве можно обосновать здесь отсутствие запятой после "пожалуй"?_ === Ой, конечно же нет! Ведь специально применил скобки, чтобы обособить "пожалуй", и почему-то потерял эту запятую при печати, СПАСИБО!

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем здесь скобки. Это обычное предложение с обособленным дополнением, внутри которого находится вводное слово. Как известно, скобками выделяются вставные предложения как разновидность вводных, а в данном предложении этой конструкции нет. Итак: Все наши знакомые, кроме, пожалуй, одного, переболели этой зимой гриппом.